# flutter - Native Ads wont load & show and also it's event callback not showing anything

Tags: android, flutter, admob, ads, native-ads

While waiting for official Admob's **Native Ads** for a flutter, I try to integrate it using 3rd party plugin.

I try using a plugin that claimed can show **Admob's Native Ads** [here](https://pub.dev/packages/native_ads).

However, **the native ads wont load & show on Android Devices** (iOS not yet tested).

**The event callback** also not showing anything.

I have submitted an issue [here](https://github.com/sakebook/flutter_native_ads/issues/23), but I think the author may be busy, so I post also here.

Below are my codes:

For **Initialization**:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with AfterLayoutMixin<HomeScreen> {

  @override
    void initState() {
      // TODO: implement initState
      super.initState();      
      NativeAds.initialize();
      ...
    }
```

For **NativeAds** placement is under below structures:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar( .. ),
        body: OfflineBuilder(
              connectivityBuilder: (BuildContext context, ConnectivityResult connectivity, Widget child) {
                  ...  
                  child: NestedScrollView(
                      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) { ... }
                      body: RefreshIndicator(
                        backgroundColor: Pigment.fromString(UIData.primaryColor),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onRefresh: () => homeBloc.init(),
                        child: ListView(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                            ...
                              ListView(
                                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                children: <Widget>[

                                ...


                                SizedBox(
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  height: 320,
                                  child: NativeAdView(
                                    onParentViewCreated: (_) {
                                      print("sinative create.....");
                                    },
                                    androidParam: AndroidParam()
                                      ..placementId = "ca-app-pub-xxx" //my admob
                                      ..packageName = "com.apps.myapp"
                                      ..layoutName = "native_ad_layout"
                                      ..attributionText = "AD",
                                    iosParam: IOSParam()
                                      ..placementId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511" // test
                                      ..bundleId = "{{YOUR_IOS_APP_BUNDLE_ID}}"
                                      ..layoutName = "{{YOUR_CREATED_LAYOUT_FILE_NAME}}"
                                      ..attributionText = "SPONSORED",
                                    onAdImpression: () => print("native is show"),
                                    onAdClicked: () => print("onAdClicked!!!"),
                                    onAdFailedToLoad: (Map<String, dynamic> error) => print("native is error ==> $error"),
                                  ),
                                ),                      

                                ...

                                ...
```

Any Idea?

Thanks In Advance...

**==Update (After Itiel Maimon's suggestion)**

I have place initialization in `main.dart` before runApp(), but in debug i got below error:

```
E/flutter (10737): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel native_ads)
E/flutter (10737): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:314:7)
E/flutter (10737): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10737): #1      new NativeAds.initialize (package:native_ads/native_ads.dart:5:14)
E/flutter (10737): #2      main.<anonymous closure> (package:apps789apps/main.dart:35:15)
E/flutter (10737): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
E/flutter (10737): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (10737): #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
E/flutter (10737): #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
E/flutter (10737): #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
E/flutter (10737): #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
E/flutter (10737): #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
E/flutter (10737): #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
E/flutter (10737): #11     SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations (package:flutter/src/services/system_chrome.dart)
E/flutter (10737): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10737): #12     main (package:apps789apps/main.dart:31:16)
E/flutter (10737): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10737): #13     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:229:25)
E/flutter (10737): #14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
E/flutter (10737): #15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
E/flutter (10737): #16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
E/flutter (10737): #17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1500:12)
E/flutter (10737): #18     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:221:5)
E/flutter (10737): #19     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:305:19)
E/flutter (10737): #20     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

any idea to solve ?

Comment: In general, admob takes times to get an advert for new Apps. Did you try using https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads test id?

Comment: @DharmendraPratapSingh Yes i have tried it but no success...

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the `NativeAds.initialize();` on the initState() method.
Put it before you call runApp().
e.g `void main() {
  NativeAds.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
}`

Also make sure you are using Admob [test ad unit ids](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads), otherwise you will not see any ads.

If it still isn't working, try to use the [NativeAdViewWrapper](https://github.com/sakebook/flutter_native_ads/blob/master/example/lib/native_ad_view_wrapper.dart) by using `child: const NativeAdViewWrapper(),` at the requested place.

Comment: i have followed all of your suggestion, but now get an error `MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel native_ads` (please see my updated question). thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this plugin [flutter_native_admob](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_admob), I am using in some of my apps and it's pretty good and easy.

```
// Initialize using you APPID
NativeAdmob().initialize(appID: APP_ID);

// Show the Native Ad Widget inside your list/grid..
NativeAdmobBannerView(
            adUnitID: Ads.NATIVE_ID,
            style: BannerStyle.light,
            showMedia: true,
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/native_ads

A new Package for Native Ads available. Try this.

**Supported native ads fields**

1. Headline(Required)
2. Body(Required)
3. Call To Action(Required)
4. Ad Attribution(Required)
5. Media
6. Icon
7. Star
8. rating
9. Store
10. Price
11. Advertiser

**Event callback**

Receive callbacks for some events by passing to the NativeAdView constructor

1. onAdImpression
2. onAdClicked
3. onAdFailedToLoad
4. onAdLeftApplication
5. onAdLoaded

Right now **No support Mediation Ads.** Check the official link given above for new features